# Graphics Card Problems with Lenovo ideapad Z570 w/ Nvidia 520m

Tags: 11.10, command-line, lenovo, nvidia-optimus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

My lenovo Z570 have 2 Graphic cards Intel HD and Nvidia 520m. In Ubuntu 11.04 I used wobbly windows which but now in 11.10 I cannot use it.

When my system shows me restricted drivers available I downloaded them, installed them and reboot but no difference. If I am gonna use GNOME without Nvidia Drivers It looks excellent, After installing them and rebooting system goes into classic mode.

And I tried to do something I saw searching on net, but that ended with a black screen after booting windows or just a terminal asking my username and password nothing else. The result of that was reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch.